# Make and distribution tool for php

Tags: php, makefile, phpunit, build-automation, simpletest

I've seen some questions but none really answers what I have in mind; all developers are working with the one or the other framework but none has started something of their own otherwise they would have the same question:

I have some php classes on the server, say A.php, B.php and C.php ready to distribute to my users, in the following tree structure:

```
 /
 |-dir-1
 |  |-A.php
 |  |-B.php
 |
 |-dir-2
    |-C.php
```

A developer builds D.php and E.php **extending** the above tree-application and then, he intends to distribute these to other users who already have the basic classes.

My question is: can we use a simple tool to make projects on top of the existed tree, extract and pack the project's files and disseminate to users **without installing** tons of pear this and pear that?

And if there is such a tool can I use it decentralized i.e. one copy for every developer building on top of the existing tree (application) a copy of which is already located at the developer's home? (yes, each developer works on his own copy!)

A similar answer for a **test suite** would be appreciated (I tend to [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/)).
Many Thanks.

Comment: I suppose I didn't fully understand what you're looking for... For me it sounds like you need a source code repository (like git) and a package manager (like composer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a version control system such as GIT or SVN?